# sonos integration with announcement system

Tags: node.js, sonos

I am currently looking into the possibility of integrating an announcement system with sonos but have yet to find a reasonable approach and have started wondering if it is currently possible at all.

My initial approach was having songs subscribe to a radio station that would send a constant stream of announcements. After testing with this setup I have been unable to get the delay below 3 seconds (which is too long).

I then began looking into the sonos [API](http://musicpartners.sonos.com/) Looking at documentation and the below graph I came to the conclusion that what I was trying to achieve was however possible with sonos.[image: sonos graph]

It does seem however that it will require substantial effort to implement a service where I can stream audio to sonos directly so I was hoping I could get some things cleared up before I proceed with a rather costly implementation. (time)

1. Is it possible to get audio delay below 3 seconds when streaming directly?
2. Am I correct in understanding that I will need to write an app on the sonos platform to handle my requests?
3. If the answer to above is no; what other options are available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSB,

Our current public APIs are really not well designed for what you are trying to do.  There are some open source projects which are working off reverse engineered APIs that may work a little better for you.

Comment: Does Sonos offer any other means to provide this functionality or does it plan to do so in the future? I would love to be able to create a fully integrated Sonos experience as user experience is key for what I am trying to achieve, and as such I am a bit weary of using reverse engineered APIs that could change at any time.

Comment: additionally: should I hook my system up to a playbar or play5 enable me to have live playback of the audio? (Seeing as the Sonos system somehow manages to do this for playing back audio in synch with the video of a TV)

Comment: I cannot comment on future plans, but I understand your concern and this is an area that we will continue to investigate. The play 5 does not do truly synced audio (there is higher latency), but using the optical input on the playbar is very low latency.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [my library](https://github.com/svrooij/node-sonos-ts) to [play a notification](https://svrooij.io/node-sonos-ts/sonos-device/notifications-and-tts.html).

```js
const SonosDevice = require('@svrooij/sonos').SonosDevice
const sonos = new SonosDevice(process.env.SONOS_HOST || '192.168.96.56')

sonos.PlayNotification({
    trackUri: 'https://cdn.smartersoft-group.com/various/pull-bell-short.mp3', // Can be any uri sonos understands
    // trackUri: 'https://cdn.smartersoft-group.com/various/someone-at-the-door.mp3', // Cached text-to-speech file.
    onlyWhenPlaying: false, // make sure that it only plays when you're listening to music. So it won't play when you're sleeping.
    timeout: 10, // If the events don't work (to see when it stops playing) or if you turned on a stream, it will revert back after this amount of seconds.
    volume: 15, // Set the volume for the notification (and revert back afterwards)
    delayMs: 700 // Pause between commands in ms, (when sonos fails to play sort notification sounds).
  })
  .then(played => {
    console.log('Played notification %o', played)
  })
```

Works in node/typescript and has a lot of possibilities.